# Can SPARQL be used to query the following from an ontology?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege, dotnetrdf

Can SPARQL be used to query an empty ontology (with no individuals), to retrieve information about the restrictions (axioms or object properties) put on a class?

Here's a snippet of my ontology in turtle syntax:

[image]

How can a SPAQRL query, if possible, be formulated to retrieve the following triples from the ontology:

[image]

And if not possible to do this directly with SPARQL, is there a workaround for it using dotNetRDF OntologyAPI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's indeed possible. You already have the Turtle snippet - SPARQL is close to Turtle. Just replace the entities you're interested in by variables. And for the list values you"ll need property paths

Comment: By the way, are you sure that you want `owl:intersectionOf (Step1 Step2 Step3 Step4)`? this means Activity1 consists only of individuals that belong to all of these classes at the same time. It's not the same as the logical OR.

Comment: `PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
 WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf [owl:onProperty ?predicate; owl:allValuesFrom/owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?object] }`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! really appreciate it!

Comment: I chose intersectionOf because Activity1 needs all those steps to be present.

Comment: But that's wrong. Lets rewrite your axiom in Manchester Syntax, more redable for humans and also the input language in the GUI of Protege; `Activity1 SubClassOf: Process1 AND (consistsOf ONLY (Step1 AND Step2 AND Step3 AND Step4) )` - First of all, you used `ONLY` - this doesn't ask for existence but restricts all existing occurences of `consistsOf`. Second, you have `Step1 AND Step2 AND Step3 AND Step4` which covers all instances that belong to each of those classes - I don't think this is the case in your data.

Comment: I think what you really want is `Activity1 SubClassOf: Process1 AND (consistsOf SOME Step1 AND consistsOf SOME Step2 AND consistsOf SOME Step3 AND  consistsOf SOME Step4 )` - do you see the difference?

Comment: Whenever possible, please use text instead of screenshots in your questions.